# sending mail from phpmailer is working but cakephp mail is not working with saim cradienial

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, phpmailer

**Hii i am using phpmailer to send mail its working fine but in cake php it's not working .
please have a look the Configuration**

**For PhpMailer :**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAuth = false; 
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "order@domain.in";
$mail->Password = "password";
```

**For CakePhp :**

```
public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('order@domain.in' => 'My domain'),
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 25,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'order@domain.in',
    'password' => 'password',
    //'client' => null,
    //'log' => false,
);
```

I find out  following thing is doing the job for Phpmailer .

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
```

please any one assist me what is alternative of **SMTPSecure** and **SMTPAuth** in cakephp

Comment: Try changing port number to 587.

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass SSL parameter in context as an array.

```
 public $SendMail = array(
  'host' => 'smtp.host.com',
  'port' => 587, 
  'username' => 'username@domain.com',
  'password' => 'password',       
  'transport' => 'Smtp',
  'SMTPSecure' => 'tls',
  'tls' => true,
  'context'=>array('ssl' => array(
      'verify_peer' => false,
      'verify_peer_name' => false,
      'allow_self_signed' => true
    )), 
 );
```